# How to plot heatmap of 4 variables?

Tags: python, plot, heatmap

I have three input variables and one output variable. I want to plot a heatmap using these 4 variables.

I found some examples of plotting 3 variables but that doesn't help in my case as I have 4 variables.

```
Input:
X = [3,7,5,1,5,0,8,1,4]
Y = [1,5,0,8,1,4,3,7,5]
Z = [8,1,4,1,5,0,5,2,3]

M = [6,4,3,5,9,8,0,4,2]
```

Output: heat map.

I am new to data plotting and visualization techniques so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to draw it? You will have a 3D cube for which you will not look inside. Nobody uses 3D heatmaps, as I know. If you want to analyze many-dimensions data series, you can draw heatmap "scatter matrix".

Comment: I want a 2d heatmap plot for it.